# How can I use private Nexus (without HTTPS) repository with Gradle for developing java application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have locally deployed the **nexus repository** for **maven-snapshots**.
I has a spring boot application (java).

I need to publish some projects to this repository, and then connect these libraries to other projects using the nexus repository.

- gradle version

```yaml
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-86)
```

- published artifact

**gradle.buid**

```yaml
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

group = 'com.model'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "http://localhost:8081/repository/model-snapshot/"
    setAllowInsecureProtocol(true);
  }
}

ext {
  springJacksonVersion = "2.13.4"
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:' + springJacksonVersion
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

publishing  {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/repository/model-snapshot/") {
        authentication(userName: "user", password: "1")
        setAllowInsecureProtocol(true);
      }
      pom.version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      pom.artifactId = "m-entities"
      pom.groupId = "com.model"
    }
  }
}
```

> - Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':m-entities'.
>   ....
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method publishing() for arguments [build_7pz2gcbsao2wyri8rdvmjwrzm$_run_closure5@482a5d97] on project ':m-entities' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMissingMethodExecutionFailed.(AbstractDynamicObject.java:190)
>   at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:184)
>   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.methodMissingException(BasicScript.java:162)
>   at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:167)
>   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:84)
>   at build_7pz2gcbsao2wyri8rdvmjwrzm.run

- the project in which the **library** is connected, which should be published in the nexus repository

**gradle.build**

```yaml
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.model'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'm-shapshot'
        url "http://localhost:8081/repository/model-snapshot/"
        setAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
        credentials {
            username project.repoUser
            password project.repoPassword
        }}

}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.4")
    set('testcontainersVersion', "1.17.4")
    mapStructVersion = '1.5.3.Final'
    mEntitiesVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    implementation 'com.model:m-entities:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${testcontainersVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

- gradle.properties

```yaml
repoUser=user
repoPassword=1
```

> Could not GET 'http://localhost:8081/repository/model-snapshot/com/model/m-entities/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
> Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Does anyone have any ideas on how to configure uploading artifacts to the local nexus repository and using this repository to get the artifacts published there ?

Answer (score 0):

in the publishing project - can you try below

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.model'
            artifactId = 'm-entities'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

publishing  {
  repositories {
      maven(url: "http://localhost:8081/repository/model-snapshot/") {
        authentication(userName: "user", password: "1")
        setAllowInsecureProtocol(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a error: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'planner-entities'.
> Could not find method repository() for arguments [{url=http://localhost:8081/repository/.........}, build_7pz2gcbsao2
wyri8rdvmjwrzm$_run_closure6$_closure12$_closure13@1c695fad] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.
dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandle

Comment: it should be maven instead of repository

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
plugins {
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
  id 'java-library'
}

configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

ext {
  springJacksonVersion = "2.13.4"
  nameSnapshotRepo = 'repo-shapshot'
  urlPSnapshotRepo = 'http://localhost:8081/repository/repo-snapshot/'
  artefact = 'your-starter' /*like title of name project catalog*/
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    name "${nameSnapshotRepo}"
    url "${urlSnapshotRepo}"
    setAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
    credentials {
      username 'admin'
      password 'admin'
    }
  }
```

During the build, a warning will appear, how to remove it, I do not know. But this code allows you to publish artifacts to Nexus, which works over HTTP.